# Do smaller transistors improve computational efficiency because they decrease the duration of signal transfer?

Tags: transistors, computer-architecture, efficiency

There has been a massive improvement of computational power of computers per $ over time. As far as I understand, this has been driven almost completely by the massive  increase in transistors per unit area.

**What drives the fact that cost/compute goes down because transistors/millimeter goes up?**

By **compute** I mean "operations per second", e.g. flops.

Note: I am ignoring the fact that smaller computers are intrinisically desirable, e.g. because it means you can have a computer in your phone. I am just asking about the cost per compute, so think e.g. in the context of a cloud computer, where size doesn't *intrinsically* matter to a consumer.

Here are some of the possible channels I can think of:

- less surface area per transistor means less raw material cost per transistor.
- less surface area per transistor means less signal travel time between transistors, so more compute per transistor.
- smaller transistor size means less heat production per operation, so less energy cost in $.

**What is the relative importance of these factors? Are there other important factors?**

Comment: Very good question unfortunately it is impossibly broad to answer in this format. A google search for moore's law will return a large number of articles covering this topic.

Comment: @RoyC, I don't have a background in electrical engineering. Can you recommend an article?

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/processors-process-size/

Comment: @RoyC, I was looking for something more formal/precise, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> less surface area per transistor means less signal travel time between transistors, so more compute per transistor.

This is basically true; the other important factor is that smaller, narrower gates have a lower gate capacitance. The time taken to switch a transistor is approximately(+) the time taken to charge its capacitance through the resistance of the wires and driving transistor.

> smaller transistor size means less heat production per operation

Only partly true - they take less energy to drive on the input, but all other things being equal a smaller transistor will have a higher on-resistance and emit more heat. This is increasingly a problem and why Intel is building chips where you can't have all the parts of the processor on at once.

> less surface area per transistor means less raw material cost per transistor.

Raw material cost is pretty trivial. *Processing* cost for materials is huge, and is where most of the non-design costs come from. The silicon wafers are expensive to make and very expensive to process, especially in the newer, narrower processs. Costs of the order of $10k - $20k for an eight-inch circular wafer. So the more chips you can fit on a wafer the better.

There is also the yield issue. If you imagine manufacturing defects being randomly distributed, put (say) ten spots on the wafer. Those ten spots will be failures. This means that doing 100 chips/wafer will waste 10% of them, but 1000 chips/wafer will waste 1% of them.

(+) yes I know Elmore delay is a simplification

Answer (score 0):

When talking compute/unit currency, this usually means we are discussing datacenter computing/supercomputers/workstations etc. In these cases, compute cost translates almost 1-to-1 onto compute/energy: the consumed energy is the main cost.

So, you will actually find that it is not really the fact that the density of transistors goes down that reduces cost. Rather, it is the effects this has on energy use.

Often, digital designers will split the power consumption up into two parts: Leakage, or static power consumption, and dynamic power consumption.

**Leakage power**

Leakage is exactly what it sounds like: current that 'leaks' from VDD to ground. This is because the transistor in Off state still has some current flowing through it. This current might be very, very small (pA or even lower) but there are also a lot of transistors (hundreds of millions to billions), so in the end all this adds up. Leakage used to be a non-issue. However, as the transistor gets smaller, the current has cross a shorter distance between drain and source. As a result, leakage goes up. This is shown in this picture, which I got from [Chen, Mu-Yen & Chen, Da-Ren & Hsieh, Shuming. (2014). A Blocking-Aware Scheduling for Real-Time Task Synchronization Using a Leakage-Controlled Method](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Leakage-versus-dynamic-power-trend-1-19-20_fig5_269828466):

[image]

**Dynamic power**

When we look at a series of logic gates in CMOS, we can actually think of all the inputs as capacitors \$^1\$. When we want to change the voltage on the input (turn a 1->0 or 0->1) we need to charge or discharge this capacitor.

Charging and discharging this capacitor is done by the output of the stage driving the gate. Charging, in essence, means taking charge from VDD and putting it into that capacitor. Discharging means taking that charge out of the capacitor again to bring it down to ground. As a result, that charge went from VDD to ground, which means we used up some energy \$^2\$. This energy is the dynamic energy. If we decrease the size of the capacitor, we need less charge to 'fill' it, which means less energy per charge/discharge cycle. And that is precisely what happens with newer, smaller transistors - as they get smaller, the capacitance decreases, and as a result the energy per computation decreases.

However, as I already said, the gains had by decreasing the size of the transistors are slowly diminishing. Instead, other tricks are used to decrease power consumption, such as supply gating (turning off what you don't use so it doesn't leak), lower supply voltages, multiple supply domains with different voltages (only use a lot of voltage where you need high speed), clever tricks in the transistors themselves (backgate control in SoI, finfets), and finally by using smarter architectures that can use much lower supplies (transmission gates for example).

I would finally like to point out that I ignored other effects, such as the increased efficiency we can get in our DC/DC conversion, the fact that our power supplies are going lower and lower, etc.

\$^1\$ In the newest technologies, the capacitance between wires is actually as big, or even bigger, as the capacitance of the gates themselves. As a result, we gain less with smaller and smaller transistors.

\$^2\$ it is more accurate to say we dissipated it in the form of heat in all lossy parts of the network

Answer (score 0):

The heat loss per Gflop is reduced by high tech edge coupled CO2 laser lithography than can etch a very short % of its optical wavelength.

With advances in  CMOS layered design, results in lower operating core voltage<1V, higher density cells, lower Ciss,Coss, lower RdsOn (<25 )thus faster transition speeds at lower dynamic current losses.

When reaching >1GHz switching speeds, gains with multiple cores is more efficient than N x freq. which is supported by the advances in OS and drivers to use core and thread sharing.

Advances in PLL CPU design and dynamic clock switching also allows dynamic Vdd at lower voltage and speeds to consume less power when CPU usage is low.

The next quantum step in laser lithography using EUV requires more explosive energy and higher E fields that cause breakdown induced failures from parts per billion contaminants in the wafer reducing yields and raising cost of maintenance of production equipment. But the quantum leap in performance may be affordable to some.

Transfer time is not the critical factor, rather, it is the higher capacitance of smaller gaps that must be chosen to achieve this result with the dV/dt=Vdd/(RdsOn*Ciss) which demands that the gate threshold is <1/2 of Vdd

Comment: The iOS platform likes to make changes as I peek and fat finger poke. @Scott can ye no understand anything I said?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of compute you are considering.

For serial compute, or at least tasks that are not highly parallel, increases in performance are due to a combination of lower capacitance per gate enabling more gate transtions per second, and to a lesser extent having more transistors available enabling more work to be performed per cycle.

For highly parallel applications, like graphics computing or deep learning, most of the increase comes from putting more and more parallel hardware onto chips. For example, my old TNT2 ran at 125 MHz and did two operations per cycle. A new 2080 TI, also from Nvidia, runs at 1500MHz but can now issue 4352 operations per cycle. It's therefore improved by a factor of ~10 in clockspeed and a factor of ~2000 by simply packing more hardware units in parallel.

Due to the better scaling of parallel vs. serial hardware, you can see why CPU performance has improved much slower than GPU or machine learning performance.